# Put Scripts at the Bottom

Tags: javascript

[Yslow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) recommends that you should put scripts at the bottom of the page.

Where exactly should I put them, after the body end tag?

My whole site runs in jquery, so all the javascript files are needed at the beginning. If I move them to the end, it might stop my site from working. That being the case, where instead should i put these scripts for best performance?

Comment: Why are the scripts needed at the beginning? If you put *all* it should work fine. You have to put them before the `body` closing tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is the best place to put <script> tags in HTML markup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should put them right before the closing body tag. Make sure your scripts are being initiated properly using

```
$(document).ready()
```

And you should have no issues.

Comment: shld i put the $(document).ready() part also at end of page ?

Comment: Yes, all js should be at the bottom.

Comment: Hmm could you maybe post what files you are doing this with and how in the main post? Also main thing is to make sure you have jquery loading BEFORE calling document.ready

Answer (score 0):

you should put them just before the ending body tag `</body>`