# Display div tag as Webpage title

Tags: php, javascript, css, html

I want to display a div tag as Webpage Title

Suppose my div tag

```
 <div id="songArtist"></div>
```

has a content of "Akon" then my title of page should be Akon

Adding div tag between this `<title></title>` is not working

Please help me..

Comment: You can set the document.title in javascript when the change event fires on the div element

Comment: You don't need the div tag - just the text: `<title>Akon</title>`

Comment: div tag content is not static, it will change dynamically @Pete

Comment: Are you changing this content server side or client side?

Comment: so at the end of the js function that changes the content you can just do what gareththegeek says and change your title using document.title

Answer (score 1):

Check this -

Instead of **Random Title** it will show div content(Akon in this case).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Random Title</title>

</head>

<body>
<div id="songArtist">Akon</div>
<script>
document.title = document.getElementById("songArtist").innerHTML;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

After any call to the function, object, request that changes the content of

```
 <div id="songArtist"></div>
```

dynamically, you can then call the below in Javascript;

```
 doocument.title = document.getElementById('songArtist').innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

### jQuery solution

Try this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    document.title = $('#songArtist').text();
});
```

---

If you want it to change on every change occurring to this `div` then you'd use:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('div').on( '#songArtist', 'change', function() {
        document.title = $(this).text();
    });
});
```

Comment: This question hasn't been tagged with jquery

Comment: @Pete The question is also tagged with php :|

Comment: If it changes dynamically, use javascript.

Comment: You need to include `jquery.js` above every other `script` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the title like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>hi</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id='songArtist'> Welcome to this page </div>

       <script language="javascript" >
    document.title= document.getElementById('songArtist').innerHTML;
   </script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037725/is-it-wrong-to-place-the-script-tag-after-the-body-tag. You'll want to move that `script` chunk *before* the closing `body` tag.

Comment: No we need to write this script at the end of body load. If we put the script before body tag then script will try to set the title before drawing the div control in body. And this code will not work. We only add the script on the top if we reference any file to do manupulation on body load.

Comment: Please look at the question I linked to. You have your script **outside** of the `body`. You want to add it just before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: Oh.. Sorry for this. Yes you can write at the bottom of body tag.

Answer (score -1):

**With PHP**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $page_title;?></title> 
    </head>
</html>
```

**Static title.**

```
   <html>
        <head>
            <title>
                Akon
            </title>
        </head>
    </html>
```

Comment: His page title changes on a dynamic basis.