# What happens if the script tags are present after </body>?

Tags: performance, browser

I mistakenly added  tag after  in my code. But I inspect the document in browser, is was added into before .

My doubt is what happens if the script tags are present after ? Will it cause any performance or rendering problem?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037725/is-it-wrong-to-place-the-script-tag-after-the-body-tag

Comment: Don't expect the universe to implode, and don't expect it not to. Above all, don't expect today's answer to still be true tomorrow, across all browsers, platforms, and versions. That's what "undefined" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on what the scripts do....placing javascript after the closing body element can dramatically help your site, or it can dramatically hurt your site. but you'll notice the hurt immediately for the most part. typically they are put @ the bottom to fire off after pageload; it helps with wpo, and is a nifty form of progressive enhancement if you chose to go that route. 
so if you're making a maps page that fills the entire viewport, you're not going to want to place the map lib script or api call after the body element in this case. you're relying on those scripts to load your content. but other scripts that are not vital to load, you should defer to maximize your loadspeed. it's also good practice for third-party scripts, in case they go down, you're not tied to their script onload, which will bring you down too. i also put my analytics (third-party), and form validation scripts after closing body; they are pointless until the document has loaded, why burden the user?