# Force javascript onload handler to the back of the queue

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, event-handling

I want to add a javascript file to very end of footer.php with an wordpress plugin. i tried it using 'add_action' Hook. But this hook is adding javascript nearby `</body>` tag.

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'my_fucntion()');
```

How can i push my javascript to very end of footer.php

Comment: no its not actually i want my javascript after `</html>` tag
how i can push my javascript at very end of the html output

Comment: That would be invalid. An HTML DOM consists of a single, root node, which is the `<html>` tag. Tags aren't allowed outside of the actual HTML (which makes sense if you think about it). Again: do some research [script tags go in the head or body tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037725/is-it-wrong-to-place-the-script-tag-after-the-body-tag) for a reason. It only took me a minute to google-search this, and come up with these links

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem  yes i know that but i want to alter some values with this javascript.

Comment: Use a bloody event `onload`, `onreadystatechange`... allow you to execute the JS only when the things that you want to change are there, and ready to be manipulated

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem This javascript changes normal links to affiliate links. Other networks are using same technology. if an affiliate put those javascript from two different networks then the javascript at the end of the page will win.

Thats why i want my javascript at very end of the page

Comment: That sounds very obtrusive and hack-ish o.O

Comment: @Cerbrus no its not hack-ish. Now affiliates have to add affiliates links manually. with this plugin  they dont have to add link manually this javascript will detect domains and then will alter the link with affiliate links

Comment: *"javascript at the end of the page will win"* <-- That's a hack.

Comment: @mohit: TMTOWTDI, and your current approach sounds like an ugly hack. I'm not saying that what you're doing is bad or hacky, but the way you're going about your business certainly is. Besides: JS at the end of the page doesn't get executed if previous scripts contain an error

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Whats the Other way ?

Comment: Besides, what you (apparently) really want is your JavaScript to be the **last** to execute. There is no way to guarantee that. (aside from running it in a page unload event, but that'd be pointless)

Comment: @mohit: The right question is: _How many other ways_ but basically: you have no _real_ control over the queue, but there are some tricks, I'll post a simple one as answer

Comment: so there is no way to do that right ?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem ok i am waiting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update*
There's a better way, the one below should work, but this one should be safer, still (and it's easier, IMO).
Given that JS is single-threaded, an event will push the handler to the back of the queue anyway, so if your `onload` handler ends up being called prior to another handler, dispatching a new event, that calls a handler that actually does the work you want/need to do is probably your best bet:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function rmMe()
{
    var handler = function()
    {
        window.removeEventListener('click', handler, false);//remove this listener, too
        var i, links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
        for (i=0;i<links.length;++i)
        {
            //do stuff with links
        }
    };
    window.removeEventListener('load', rmMe, false);
    window.addEventListener('click', handler, false);//bind new listener
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));//calls handler, last handler in queue
},false);
```

That might be your best bet...

---

After those endless comments, it would apear that you're looking for a way to guarantee that your JS gets executed after the page has loaded, and all other possible `onload` event handlers have been called.
The simple answer is: you can't. Not really. JS's event loop is beyond your control, but there are a few tricks that *do* work in most cases:

1. Add your script to the bottom of the body tag
2. Bind your event listener but wrap it in a `setTimeout` with zero or 1 ms delay
3. to be safe, let the event handler set another timeout that actually calls the function that does the work, this time, use a timeout that allows for a queued handler to be called. This is optional, because the queue is probably empty already
4. ***important*** make sure (or hope) that other handlers don't call `stopPropagation` on the event: this'll result in your listener *not* getting called. That's why the first method is preferable: it pushes a new handler to the back of the queue, allowing you to bind your listener first.

Code example:

```
setTimeout(function()
{
    window.onload = function()
    {
        var handler = function()
        {
            var i, links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
            for (i=0;i<links.length;++i)
            {
                //do stuff with links
            }
        };
        return function()
        {//fake, initial handler
            setTimeout(handler, 40);//optional, return handler; should suffice
        };
    };
},1);
```

That's all there is too it. This code, to be clear, goes here in the DOM:

```
        <script>
            //code here
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is not 100% reliable, but most browsers queue event handlers as they are being bound:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){}, false);//likely to be called first
window.addEventListener('load', function(){}, false);//likely to be called second
```

and so on. Not sure about this, but I wouldn't be surprised if listeners that are bound using the `window.addEventListener` are more likely to be appended to the end of the queue, as the `addEventListener` call may cause overhead. Probably use:

```
setTimeout(function()
{
    window.addEventListener('load', function tmpLoad()
    {
        var handler = function()
        {
            var i, links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
            for (i=0;i<links.length;++i)
            {
                //do stuff with links
            }
        };
        return function()
        {//fake, initial handler
            window.removeEventListener('load', tmpLoad, false);//adds overhead and time
            setTimeout(handler, 40);//optional, return handler; should suffice
        };
    },false);
},1);
```

You could also consider manually dispatching an event, after a timeout, bind a new listener, and then do: `window.dispatchEvent(new Event('load'));` to call the handler.

Comment: I was afraid you'd use a `setTimeout()` :P
Still, this should work. +1

Comment: @Cerbrus: In my last edit, I also hinted at creating your own event chain, dispatching a series of events might also work: a new event gets added to the back of the queue, so using that handler might do the trick, too, no?

Comment: That might also work, yea.

Comment: @mohit: NP, you'll have to work on X-browser issues if you want to support older versions of IE, though. `addEventListener` vs `attachEvent` and all that, but that's your job now. If you're stuck with that, you can always post a follow-up. Also read point 4 (just added), stopPropagation is unlikely on a load event, but _can_ happen