# Explain this DOM traversal order

Tags: javascript

I wrote the following page as a DOM traversal demo:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DOM Traversal</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Sample H1</h1>
        <div id="text">
            <p>Sample paragraph</p>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        // Traversing the DOM tree
        "use strict";

        var node = document.body;

        while(node) {
            console.log(node);
            node = node.lastChild;
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Surprisingly, the output I'm getting is the `body` tag followed by the `script` tag. How is this possible? Isn't the `script` tag a sibling of the `body` tag? Also, why aren't the child nodes of `body` being traversed?

Comment: Scripts should be inside the body. Perhaps your browser is correcting your non-standard markup for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037725/is-it-wrong-to-place-the-script-tag-after-the-body-tag

Comment: @isherwood: or in the `<head>`...

Comment: Right. I meant as opposed to after it.

Comment: Just tested your code in several browsers. it seems that most of them show script as a sibling of body and as a child of it (it shows up twice, with the same content). And on all of them it does traverse the children as well (please read Uweb's answer to see why it might not for you)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot add your `script` element outside of the `head` or `body` elements. The browser is auto-correcting your HTML, moving the `script` into the end of your `body`, which explains the result you are getting.

The `html` element may only contain the `head` and `body` elements as its children. Anything else must be placed within these two elements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please see my updated code here http://pastebin.com/4n97tv4v. I should now get body -> div -> p but am getting body -> #text (would be great if you could run this at your end). What's wrong now?

Comment: Text is also a node which means that the blank space between your elements is actually a text node. That's what you receive.

Answer (score 4):

On top of what iMoses said, your script block will run before the entire document is parsed, as it doesn't wait on the domReady event. This seems to cause a race condition.

If you leave your script where it is, but wait for domReady, you get a slightly different result (albeit still not what you want).

EDIT: change your script to output "node.outerHTML" instead, and you will see that the script block gets moved or rather duplicated into the body.
Without waiting for document ready, you end up with two script blocks while the script is running - one is your original, the other one at the end of the body as iMoses pointed out.
Waiting for document ready, you will find that only the (moved) one inside the body remains.

Comment: Noticed the second block as well, but only one of them (the one inside the body) runs the code.

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start with resolving this kind of 'issue' is to validate the source first.

Tools such as the W3C HTML validator will help you avoid this kind of problem going forward:

http://validator.w3.org/check

Validating your code returns the following:

```
Line 11, Column 12: document type does not allow element "SCRIPT" here
<script>


The element named above was found in a context where it is not allowed. This could mean that you have incorrectly nested elements -- such as a "style" element in the "body" section instead of inside "head" -- or two elements that overlap (which is not allowed).

One common cause for this error is the use of XHTML syntax in HTML documents. Due to HTML's rules of implicitly closed elements, this error can create cascading effects. For instance, using XHTML's "self-closing" tags for "meta" and "link" in the "head" section of a HTML document may cause the parser to infer the end of the "head" section and the beginning of the "body" section (where "link" and "meta" are not allowed; hence the reported error).
```