# Uncaught ReferenceError: validate is not defined (jQuery validation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, grails

I am getting this error and the script never seems to work.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: validate is not defined

I also tried to call the function onsubmit from the  and also tried to place the function inside the page and in a separate JS file but same results. 
The html file:`show.gsp`

```
<body>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
        <g:form class="form-inline" role="form" action="update" name="form" >
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label class="control-label" for="mcc">GSM.Identity.MCC</label>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="mcc" id="mcc" value="${mcc}">
                <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <br/>

            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label class="control-label" for="mnc">GSM.Identity.MNC</label>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="mnc" id="mnc" value="${mnc}">
                <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <br/>

            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label class="control-label" for="co">GSM.Radio.CO</label>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="co" id="co" value="${co}">
                <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <p>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="submit" onclick="validate()">Save Settings</button>
                <g:link action="restart" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Restart OpenBts</g:link>
            </p>
        </g:form>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
<script src="${resource(dir:'js', file:'main_script.js') }"></script>
```

and the script: `main_script.js`

```
//validation script
function validate(){

    console.log("test");

    var mcc = $("#mcc").val();
    var mnc = $("#mnc").val();
    var co = $("#co").val();

    if (!$.isNumeric(mcc)){
        $("#mcc").parent("div").removeClass("has-feedback has-error has-success").addClass("has-error");
    }
    if (!$.isNumeric(mnc)){
        $("#mnc").parent("div").removeClass("has-feedback has-error has-success").addClass("has-error");
    }
    if (!$.isNumeric(co)){
        $("#co").parent("div").removeClass("has-feedback has-error has-success").addClass("has-error");
    }
}
```

Comment: `<script src="${resource(dir:'js', file:'main_script.js') }"></script>` this line should be before `</body>` tag

Comment: that did work, am having a hard time understanding why though, shouldn't it just work after the body since it's in the same page.

Comment: oh and i had a syntax error there so i fixed it. but that was not the problem so thank you again.
maybe you want to it that as answer?

Comment: I'll answer. scripts must be loaded within `<body>` tag or `<head>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript must be loaded within `<head>` or `<body>` tags.

you have added script tag after `</body>` tag, thats why it is not getting loaded and button event can't find `validate()` function which is within that Javascript

Add it before `</body>` tag as follows,

```
    .
    .
    .
            </g:form>
           </div>
         </div>

    <script src="${resource(dir:'js', file:'main_script.js') }"></script>
   </body>
```

As [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037725/is-it-wrong-to-place-the-script-tag-after-the-body-tag) says it should be used within `<body>` tag