# difference between putting scripts in body or outside body

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs

I have this structure now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- stylesheets-->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/static/stylesheets/style.css'/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,600,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link href="/static/css/bootstrap/bootstrap-notify.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/portal/simple-sidebar.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/userProfileView/user-profile.css" media="screen" />

</head>

<body>
<main>
    <div name="main-div" id="main-div-id"></div>
</main>
</body>

<% if(env == 'development') {%> 

<script data-main="/static/app/js/main" src="/static/vendor/require.js"></script>

<% } else { %>

<script src="/static/app/optimized/optimized.js"></script>

<% } %>

</html>
```

as you can see, my javascripts are "at the bottom" but they are outside the body tags, not inside.

I am sure it makes a difference, but I am not sure what difference it makes to put the scripts outside the `<head>` and outside the `<body>` tags.

Comment: I think some people do it like that so all the `HTML` is loaded so any errors aren't thrown where elements can't be found.

Comment: I would wonder if document.ready would fire sooner if the scripts are outside the body or inside? IDK

Comment: Why not have file which kick starts all your other JS and have it wrapped with `window.onload`?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Is it wrong to place the <script> tag after the </body> tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037725/is-it-wrong-to-place-the-script-tag-after-the-body-tag)

Comment: @Script47, the top answer in the duplicate directly addresses the OP's question

Comment: @Michael_B fair enough, up-voted as you're right.

Answer (score 2):

At first I thought I remembered that `<head>` and `<body>` was optional and that therefore it's okay to place `<script>` in `<html>`, but it's only partially true.

`<script>` isn't allowed inside of `<html>` because `<html>` may only contain `<head>` and `<body>`.

However if you don't declare `<body>` or `<head>` the browser will implicitly create them for you ([under the right conditions](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags)). I.e. this is invalid:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body><body>
  <script>console.log('test')</script>
</html>
```

This is implicitly creates a body element which the script tag is part of:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <script>console.log('test')</script>
</html>
```

This implicitly creates a head element which the script tag is part of:

```
<html>
  <script>console.log('test')</script>
</html>
```

So no, you should never place a `<script>` after `</body>`

Comment: @AlexMills The browser is really good at recovering from errors, but it is definitely an error. Supposedly it doesn't work in IE10, but I haven't verified.

Comment: Ok I will move it into the body just because this is the correct thing to do