# In fiddle perfectly running but NO effect of JQuery on web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I simply trying to add and remove class on li tag on click. I tried in fiddle and the JQuery is working fine but the very same code is not working on localhost.
    [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/vishalonnet123/pdzdzmbe/)

Here my page -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$('#cssmenu li').on('click', function(){
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul> 
  <li class='active'><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li> 
  <li><a href="Untitled-1.html" target="content"><span>About Us</span></a></li> 
  <li><a href="#"><span>Gallery</span></a></li> 
  <li><a href="#"><span>Alumni</span></a></li> 
  <li><a href="#"><span>Events</span></a></li> 
  <li><a href="#"><span>Polling</span></a></li> 
  <li><a href="#"><span>Feedback</span></a></li> 
  <li class='last'><a href="#"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li> 
</ul>   
</div>
```

This is a part of CSS

```
#cssmenu li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
#cssmenu li a {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 15px 9px 15px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#cssmenu li.active {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #36b0b6;
}
#cssmenu li.active a {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  background: #1e6468;
  border: 1px solid #133e40;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 5px 10px #133e40;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 5px 10px #133e40;
  box-shadow: inset 0 5px 10px #133e40;
}
```

Any input greatly appreciated as I know I'm just few step away since it already does in fiddle.

Comment: What errors do you get in the console when you run it locally? Is jQuery being included?

Answer (score 1):

You attach the click handler before the DOM for that element is created. Either move it to the end of the page or put it within `$(document).ready()`

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#cssmenu li').on('click', function(){
      $('li.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
  });
})

</script>
```

Comment: Sir I checked your formula also, but not worked.

Answer (score 1):

Move this

```
<script language="javascript">
$('#cssmenu li').on('click', function(){
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
</script>
```

at the end of your `<body>` tag or have it execute on [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).

Right now it executes before your DOM is loaded and nothing happens.

UPDATE:

To answer to your comment, putting the script tag **after** the `</body>` tag is not really correct, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037725/is-it-wrong-to-place-the-script-tag-after-the-body-tag)

Anyway, try doing this then.

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#cssmenu li').on('click', function(){
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: Yup, because `#cssmenu` doesn't exist yet. Good catch.

Comment: @MitchKarajohn According to you all expert I moved the script just after </body> and before </html> and tested but no effect, I am writing this code in jsp page.

Comment: @AmitRoy Updated my answer, please check it out.

Comment: No Nothing working..! I added this file <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> is this file correct

Comment: Are you sure you are loading jQuery? If you open your console do you see any errors like '$ is not defined' or something similar?

Comment: OK I got the problem.. I require this file <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>, When I am using this line it is working, but if I am changing it to <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> it is not working.

Comment: But how can I use this jquery-latest.min.js file on localhost (means offline)

Comment: Requiring the file with `src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"` means that you have the jquery file in the same directory as your `.html` file, in your project. You probably don't have it. This `<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"; type="text/javascript"></script>` requires the file over the internet, form a place where it exists, so it works.

Comment: To use it offline, you need to download the jQuery files to your machine. I'd start from [here](https://jquery.com/download/). If my answer helped you to resolve your issue please consider marking it as an accepted answer