# Call different events when a variable change in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, events

I build a small application to switch between random images in an iframe, I would like that after 10 or 20 images the user will get an image or source I want him to get and not a random one, and then return to the loop. 
I have a problem with the count and if function, will appreciate any help. Thanks

```
<body>
  <iframe id="img_main" src="https://www.example.com/img_4.jpg" width="600" height="800" frameborder="1" scrolling="no"></iframe>
  <br>
<button id="H" type="button" onclick=(newImg(),clickCounter(),changeImg())>images</button>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
function newImg(){
var myArray = [
  "img_1.jpg",
  "img_2.jpg",
  "img_3.jpg",
  "img_4.jpg"
    ];
var imgNew = "https://example.com/"
var randomItem = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
document.getElementById("img_main").src = "https://example.com/" + randomItem ;
}

function clickCounter() {
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  if (localStorage.clickcount) {
    localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
  } else {
    localStorage.clickcount = 1;
  }

  function changeImg(){
    if (localStorage.clickcount = 10,20) {
      document.getElementById("ins_main").src = "https://example.com/pre_defined_img.jpg";
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: img.com is just a place holder in this case. if you can help with the script I'll highly appreciate it.

Comment: you are correct it should be the same. it should be img_main in both places. it was a typo.

Comment: Fixed it all, thanks for your patient.

Comment: I guess you didn't see my answer below... :/

Comment: Sorry, I just saw it, trying to understand it :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: if you have questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way I see that...

by simply use of the modulo (finds the remainder after division)
you don't need to use an iframe, img element is enough.
use an [**IIFE**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).   as closure method

> file : "myScript.js"

```
const imgBox = (function()
  {
  const refURL  = 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/'
    ,   imgName = [ '251/300/500.jpg', '252/300/500.jpg', '253/300/500.jpg', '254/300/500.jpg'
                  , '255/300/500.jpg', '256/300/500.jpg', '257/300/500.jpg', '258/300/500.jpg'
                  , '259/300/500.jpg', '260/300/500.jpg', '261/300/500.jpg', '146/300/500.jpg'
                  , '263/300/500.jpg', '264/300/500.jpg', '265/300/500.jpg', '266/300/500.jpg'
                  , '267/300/500.jpg', '268/300/500.jpg', '269/300/500.jpg', '270/300/500.jpg'
                  , '271/300/500.jpg', '272/300/500.jpg', '273/300/500.jpg', '274/300/500.jpg'
                  ]
    ,   imgZero = '250/300/500.jpg' 
    ,   imgSiz  = imgName.length
    ,   imgMain = document.getElementById('img-main')
    ;
  var imgNum = 0, randomI = 0;

  const obj =
    { setNext()
      { 
      if (!(++imgNum % 10)) // each 10 times
        {
        imgMain.src = refURL + imgZero
        }
      else
        {
        randomI = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgSiz)
        imgMain.src = refURL + imgName[randomI]
        }
      return imgNum 
      }
    }
  return obj
})()

const btImg    = document.getElementById('bt-img')
  ,   imgCount = document.getElementById('img-count')
  ,   banner   = document.getElementById('my-banner')
  ;
btImg.onclick =evt=>
  {
  let counter = imgBox.setNext()

  imgCount.textContent = counter

  if (!(counter %50))  // each 50 times..
    {
    changeBanner()
    }
  }

  //  changing banner function...
function changeBanner()
  {
  //.....
  // do what ever you want to change your banner
  }
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <style>
    img#img-main {
      width:  300px;
      height: 500px;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      padding: 2px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="img-main" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/250/300/500.jpg" alt="" >
  <p id="img-count">0</p>
  <button id="bt-img">Image change</button>

  <div id="my-banner">the banner</div>

<script src="myScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but I still have a problem...
I copy this to 3 files, html, js, and css 
And it's not working... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: THANKS, working perfectly, I placed the JS in a separate file and for some reason, it didn't work. Thanks again.

Comment: @Gil  this is what I do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39312681/where-is-the-ideal-place-to-load-javascripts-in-html/39312790#39312790  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037725/is-it-wrong-to-place-the-script-tag-after-the-body-tag/3037769#3037769  you can also follow links for explanations

Comment: Thanks again. 
I do have a small question everything is working great, but I wanted to move the button under the script and it stooped working, which is super wired, do you know why it happened? (it's in side the <body> before the </body>

Comment: @Gil I changed my answer to place the button under the image part :)  (and show you a complete html)

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I'm using the code and its great. 
I wanted to add another condition for the same imgNum and I just can do it. 
The idea I'm trying to do is to change a class name from none to block
It's a banner (image) that I want to start as hidden and when the count (imgNun) reaches 20 then it will change the class from none to block. 
the code I wrote is:
  
const banner =
    { showBanner()
      {
      imgCount.textContent = ++imgNum

      if (!(imgNum = 50)) 
        {
        document.getElementByClass('banner')= "display: block;"
        }
Please advise

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help.
I want both conditions to work. every 10 clicks to show an image and after 50 clicks to show another banner (not the same) 
Thanks

Comment: did you had time to check my last comment, thanks for the help.

Comment: adding a `changeBanner()` function