# Can't write data in txt file with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to save the value of "`src`" in a .txt file which is on my local disc at `C:\hi\data.txt`.

I think the problem is in `id: $(this).find('.src').val()` because `src` is created after a button click with the help of some JS.

I'm not fully familiar with jQuery and JS, but this is what I managed to do. The "Add Video" button works fine.

```
<body>

<input id="input" type="text" name="Youtube Source" />
<button id="button" onclick="addVideo();">Click to add video!</button>
<button id="button1">Click to save!</button>

<div id="ytContainer"></div>

</body>

<script>
var x;
function addVideo() {
    x = document.createElement("EMBED");
    x.setAttribute("src", 'https://www.youtube.com/v/' + input.value);
    document.getElementById("ytContainer").appendChild(x);
}
</script>

<script>
$("#button1").click(function ()
{
    $('#form_addjts').submit(function () {
        writeToFile({
            id: $(this).find('.src').val(),
        });
        return false;
    });
    function writeToFile(data) {
        var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var fh = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\hi\data.txt", 8);
        fh.WriteLine(data.src);
        fh.Close();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: From what I know.. Client-side script like JavaScript or jQuery do not have access to a local file system.

Comment: Are you trying this on IE Since ActiveXObject works only on IE?

Comment: that can be fixed (ActiveXObject), but can that see "src" because only after a button click it is created with js and there is no hard code of that thing.

Comment: Louys Patrice Bessette So I need to use some back-end to get that going

Comment: This could work on FireFox: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1098980, even local reading poses some security issues ... usually this depends on the local settings of each user and varies per browser, so good luck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3037792/125981  Plus you do not need multiple script tags there at the end

Comment: `fh.WriteLine(data.src);` there is no `.src` there, just `.id` in `id: $(this).find('.src').val(),` and with that trailing comma some IE versions will fail there.

Answer (score 0):

You stated the problem if the value of the src, well there is no element with the "src" class in your example.
If you were talking about the embed src, you can `$('#ytContainer').find('embed').attr('src');` 
If there is indeed an element with the class "src" that we don't see in the form that we don'T see either, the problem is probably something else.