# How to get Data correctly in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

Here is my code and I want to get `list` array and show them in `html`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="app">
            <h2>{{number}}</h2>
            <h2>Here it is!</h2>
            <div v-for="item in list">{{ item.question_text }}</div>
        </div>

    </body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            number:0,
            list : [{question_text: "apple", question_owner: "HJ", answer_owner: "1Sun"}, 
            {question_text: "banana", question_owner: "HJ", answer_owner: "1Sun"},
            {question_text: "caramel", question_owner: "HJ", answer_owner: "1Sun"},
            {question_text: "demon", question_owner: "HJ", answer_owner: "1Sun"}]

        }
    })

</script>
</html>
```

[image]

I think `Vue` was recognized rightly but some error happened while getting data, because four `div` DOM element was made well. Then, Why couldn't I get data properly??

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186997/discussion-on-question-by-1sun-how-to-get-data-correctly-in-vue-js).

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your **script** tag into **body** or **header** tags, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037725/is-it-wrong-to-place-the-script-tag-after-the-body-tag)

> It won't [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) outside of the <body> or <head> tags. It also won't
>   make much difference — unless you're doing DOM manipulations that
>   could break [IE before](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/09/03/preventing-operation-aborted-scenarios.aspx) the body element is fully loaded — to putting it
>   just before the closing </body>.

Comment: yes.. as you can see, I already put <script> code inside of <body> tags..?

Comment: I think you didn't. It is in a browser because Chrome is smart ;P but in your code it is after `</body>` tag and before `</html>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return your data:

```
data() {
  return {
    {
      number:0,
      list : [{question_text: "apple", question_owner: "HJ", answer_owner: "1Sun"}, 
        {question_text: "banana", question_owner: "HJ", answer_owner: "1Sun"},
        {question_text: "caramel", question_owner: "HJ", answer_owner: "1Sun"},
        {question_text: "demon", question_owner: "HJ", answer_owner: "1Sun"}]

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work.. but really thanks for your answer!

Comment: take a look ;) 

https://codesandbox.io/s/qx1jyv2jyw?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue