# Unable to submit form without reloading page using php and ajax call

Tags: php, jquery

I have many forms on a page. I want to submit each form without reloading page. I tried many methods but could not do. I have a form similar to this. I tried using ajax as well but could't do. Please help me. Now, I'm unable to insert in database also.

```
   <form id="a" onsubmit="return func();">
       <input type="text" name="fname">
       <input type="text" name="lname">
       <input type="text" name="email">
       <input type="submit">
      </form>
```

Jquery

```
     function func(){   
    $.ajax({
          url:'registration_detail.php?id=' +reg_id,// in this you got serialize form data via post request
        type    : 'POST',
        data    : $('#a').serialize(),
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);            
        }
    });
     return false;
}
```

Comment: you can use ajax method

Comment: @SAVe `$.post()`  is AJAX using POST method ...

Comment: I tried using ajax as well .@SAVe

Comment: I tried using ajax as well .cornel.raiu

Comment: you need to add `e.preventDefault();` at the top of your click event. It will solve your issue.

Comment: `<form action="#" id="a" method="post" onsubmit="func();return false;">` should just be `<form id='a'>` then make sure your `type` in AJAX is `method`, instead. Also, you should change those input names to ids. It will make your life easier.

Comment: I changed the question. Please help me.@StackSlave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are having a unique id for all the forms
remove `action="#"` and `onsubmit=""` from the form as you are handling the submit event in jquery

```js
        function func(id){ 
             alert($('#'+id).serialize())  
      $.ajax({
            url:'registration_detail.php',// in this you got serialize form data via post request
          type    : 'POST',
          data    : $('#'+id).serialize(),
          success: function(response){
              console.log(response);            
          }
      });
       return false;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="a" onsubmit="return func('a');">
       <input type="text" name="fname">
       <input type="text" name="lname">
       <input type="text" name="email">
       <input type="submit">
      </form>

        <form id="b" onsubmit="return func('b');">
       <input type="text" name="fname">
       <input type="text" name="lname">
       <input type="text" name="email">
       <input type="submit">
      </form>
        <form id="c" onsubmit="return func('c');">
       <input type="text" name="fname">
       <input type="text" name="lname">
       <input type="text" name="email">
       <input type="submit">
      </form>
```

`id="a"` should be unique for all the forms

in your code new variable `reg_id` will give undefined variable error, that might be the cause to reload the page.

Comment: why use `action="#"` or `onsubmit=""` when the submit handler is being added using the JS code?

Comment: You are right, i didn't noticed the jquery code, updated my answer too

Comment: I could not get succed.@ ManiMuthuPandi

Comment: where do you get issues

Comment: I''m unable to insert data in  database and the page get reloaded@ManiMuthuPandi

Comment: @PrabinaShrestha I have added the code snippet, check it, it will help you

Comment: @PrabinaShrestha upvote and accept the answer if it helps

Comment: @ ManiMuthuPandi I couldnot fixed the answer. Can you check my answer?I'm so frusted . I tried many examples.

Comment: @PrabinaShrestha just copy the html/js code from my ans its running

Comment: Can I use same form saving and editing ?ManiMuthuPandi

Comment: @PrabinaShrestha Yes you can, Please have a look `CRUD in php using Ajax`

Comment: I looked CRUD in php using Ajax .It uses different forms. How can I write like

Comment: I looked CRUD in php using Ajax .It uses different forms for edit and create. How can I use same form for create and update?@ManiMuthuPandi

Comment: I tried but couldnot succed . Please help me@ManiMuthuPandi

Answer (score 1):

Don't use " **action** " attribute not even with " **#** "

And if using AJAX, use " **Return False** "

```
    $.ajax({
        url     : "example.php",
        type    : 'POST',
        data    : $(this).serialize();
        success: function(result){
        }
    });
    return false;
```

Comment: I changed the question .I tried like this but couldnot succed

Comment: you have a typo in your answer: `serailize()` should be `serialize()`

Comment: I couldnot get succed. I updated the question.@cornel.raiu

Comment: Sorry for typo, and for multiple forms please check my latest answer

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <form  onsubmit="return func();">
        <input type="text" name="fname">
        <input type="text" name="lname">
        <input type="text" name="email">
        <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
    <script>
function func(){   
    $.ajax({
        url     : "example.php", // in this you got serialize form data via post request
        type    : 'POST',
        data    : $('form').serialize(),
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);            
        }
    });
     return false;
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a note on your placement of the `<script>` tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037725/is-it-wrong-to-place-the-script-tag-after-the-body-tag

Comment: I updated the question. I couldnot fixed it.@ cornel.raiu

Comment: @Prabina, if you have more than one form, then access the serialize value via form id.

Comment: @PankajChauhan I put form id like this  $('#a').serialize(), but still couldnot fixed it

Comment: @PrabinaShrestha,  I have tried and its working with id "a"

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you want that GET url to be POST as well. Obviously the code below won't work on this site here, but it shows concept of proper AJAX post.

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
$(function(){
var regId = 'someId';
$('#form').submit(function(e){
  $.post('registration_detail.php', 'id='+encodeURIComponent(regId)+'&'+$(this).serialize(), function(jsonObjResp){
    console.log(jsonObjResp);
  }, 'json');
  e.preventDefault();
});
}); // load end
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
#content{
  padding:7px;
}
label{
  display:inline-block; width:80px; padding-right:4px; text-align:right;
}
input[type=text]{
  width:calc(100% - 80px);
}
input{
  padding:5px 7px;
}
input[type=submit]{
  display:block; margin:0 auto;
}
#form>*{
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='content'>
    <form id='form'>
      <label for='fname'>First Name</label><input type='text' id='fname' value='' />
      <label for='lname'>Last Name</label><input type='text' id='lname' value='' />
      <label for='email'>Email</label><input type='text' id='email' value='' />
      <input type='submit' id='submit' value='submit' />
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Explain does not work. Do you have CORS access to site you are sending to?

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on("submit", function(){
    var form_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
       url     : "example.php",
       type    : 'POST',
       data    : $("#"+form_id).serialize(),
       success: function(result){
       }
    });
    return false;
    })
  })
```