# Script tag placement having weird outcomes?

Tags: html, dom, tags

the script only works if it's within the "hamburger" div, and I have no clue why? Why doesn't it work if I have it in the body or in the head? Also, I can't for the life of my have it worke if I export it to a .js file and src it into the HTML. HELP PLEASE? This is my first site and I'm already completely floored by such a simple problem....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title>My Azienda Agricola</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <div class="hamburger">
          <script>
              let test=document.getElementsByClassName("hamburger");
              test[0].style.backgroundColor="blue";
          </script>
          <div class="bar1"></div>
          <div class="bar2"></div>
          <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.querySelector()` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName()`
It's a more state of the art way to do selectors, [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
apart from this, your `.hamburger` has no width or height and cant be displayed blue if its 0px.
As you can see i added a width and height of 50px and the blue square is appearing. i didn't had your stylesheet.

this is a working example of what u try to do:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My Azienda Agricola</title>
    <style>
      .hamburger {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <div class="hamburger">
          <div class="bar1"></div>
          <div class="bar2"></div>
          <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <script>
      let test = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
      test.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can also with this example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-resonance-yxpp9?file=/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the script tag before the end of the body tag, since it won't validate outside the body or head tags. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037725/is-it-wrong-to-place-the-script-tag-after-the-body-tag) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do this this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title>My Azienda Agricola</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <div class="hamburger">
          <div class="bar1"></div>
          <div class="bar2"></div>
          <div class="bar3"></div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>

  <script src="javascript.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Then create your javascript.js file and add your script in there. Make sure it's in the same root folder as your .html file. If you put it in a folder, make sure you adjust the src according (e.g. js/javascript.js).