# js 'click' functionality/EventListener problem

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make an interactive button(to show a message in the console) with js, which just print a message in the console when the button is pressed. My js file is:

```
console.log("hello this is from cart.js")
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')

for(var i=0; i<updateBtns.length; i++){
  updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    var productId = this.dataset.product
    var action = this.dataset.action
    console.log("inside loop")
    //console.log('product ID: ', productId, "Action: ", action)
  })
}
```

HTML:

```
<button data-product="{{ i.id }}" data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn update-cart">Add to Cart</button>
```

Here inside loop message does not show anytime.... the consol just show the following message:

```
hello this is from cart.js
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://ndjpnladcallmjemlbaebfadecfhkepb/editor/config.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://ndjpnladcallmjemlbaebfadecfhkepb/editor/content.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It appears to be more of an extension issue vs your JavaScript.  Dropping it into JSFiddle works fine.  https://jsfiddle.net/dgr3t4u7/

Comment: you have to make sure your code setting up the events runs after the elements exist. If they are dynamically made/added to the document you might want to use a delegated event listener

Comment: thanks for support..... maybe it was a problem with jinja code {{ i.id }} ..... it cannot find correctly

Comment: `console.log('updateBtns', updateBtns.length);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your code works correctly when I add it to the snippet, but I think the issue might be related to how you load in your javascript code. If it is a `<script>` tag, could you make sure that it is included *after* the `body` tag?

So like this:

```html
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    ...
    <script src="your-javascript-file.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[The issue could be that your script is being executed *before* the HTML elements are created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037725/is-it-wrong-to-place-the-script-tag-after-the-body-tag).

```js
console.log("hello this is from cart.js")

const dataset  = {
  product: [
    'product-1',
    'product-2',
    'product-3'
  ],
  action: (product) => { alert(product); }
}

const updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')

for (let i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++) {
  updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    const productId = dataset.product[i]
    const action = () => {
      dataset.action(productId)
    };
    action();
    //console.log('product ID: ', productId, "Action: ", action)
  });
}
```

```html
<button class="update-cart">1</button>
<button class="update-cart">2</button>
<button class="update-cart">3</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Titulum. Now its working perfectly!..... there was just a problem with <script> tag placing.... I had put it before the body tag... now after placing it in bottom of the body tag now it is working perfectly!