# Why is my IDE giving me "errors" with this code?

Tags: html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Indus</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="game">
        <div id="character"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js">
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using Atom for this. For some reason the `</body>` and `</html>` is grayed out and the rest being properly colored. This is stopping my program from running properly (obviously)

Comment: id put it down to atom being weird because im not getting a greyed out error on pycharm or notepad++

Comment: `This is stopping my program from running properly (obviously)` I don't think that's true...?

Comment: @Dominik it's stops my program from running properly.

Comment: It would not stop your HTML from executing in your browser. HTML will close tags automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You need a closing script tag

```html
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Script tag always need to be closed even if your tag is just referencing a file, opposed to surrounding actual Javascript.

Comment: since it is an external script this wouldn't be necessary

Comment: I've never know it to be different for external scripts, but I could be wrong. I know HTML will still function if you have invalid HTML depending on where/what the errors are.

Comment: I've tried that, but I took it off because it completely grays out everything.

Comment: @cls Try it with the script tags below the body

Comment: @Uuuuuumm thanks, that helped. I'm not sure how to mark you as the answer though...

Comment: Don't put your script outside of the body...

Comment: Thx @Dominik. I retract my advice to put the script outside the body, unless you are going to put it in the head and use `defer`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037725/is-it-wrong-to-place-the-script-tag-after-the-body-tag