# Javascript onload can not be called in image

Tags: javascript, html

I want to load/replace an image at a defined location. It works with "onclick" but it doesn't work with "onload". It seems to be linked with the problem CORS (I use firefox), but I don't know how to change in my code.

The html code works well with:

```
<img id="demo" onclick="loadImg()" src="css/images/movie5.jpg"  width="100" height="232">
```

But it doesn't work with:

```
<img id="demo" onload="loadImg()" src="css/images/movie5.jpg"  width="100" height="232">
```

Where my function loadImg():

```
<script>
function loadImg() {
      document.getElementById("demo").src = "css/images/movie2.jpg";
}
</script>
```

Someone can give me a solution?

Comment: Don't use inline `style` or `on*` attributes. Start using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener - Styles or scripts should be easily debuggable and inside in their respective files or tags. Not disseminated around your document markup :)

Comment: this is because the image load event come before the script is loaded. when the js script becomes operational it waits for an event that no longer exists

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, this is just a test. I have to do a project with a given local API REST Django. The goal is to built a web which displays film images by categories. For my first idea, I have to built a pattern of images by category, for example, 4 images per category.  They are empty images at first. Then after doing the request with my API, I have the image urls, I will load them on pre-defined location (my pattern of categories). I don't know if it is a good idea to do my project? Have you got other idea about steps for building my web? Thank a lot.

Comment: @MisterJojo, I tried by adding the following code: `<script>security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy="true"</script>` and it works. I think it is really related to CORS problem but I don't know what I did is correct.

Comment: this is not a CORS problem, this a timming question, this code will never work, original image and script code cannot happen in the same time and have a reference of each other.

Answer (score 0):

The "onload" event is considered as Html Dom. If you would like to run a script through the "onload" event, you have(at least based on my knowledge) to place the script inside the body. Like the following code:

```html
<body>
<img id="demo" onload="loadImg()" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/6b/Hello_Web_Series_%28Wordmark%29_Logo.png"  width="400" height="232">
  
 <script>
function loadImg() {
      document.getElementById("demo").src = "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/word-goodbye-handwritten-whiteboard-goodbye-167996758.jpg";
}
</script>
</body>
```

You can also look into questions that are asked before:

[an onload even outside of the body tag?](https://www.webdeveloper.com/d/1168-an-onload-even-outside-of-the-body-tag)

[Is it wrong to place the  tag after the  tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037725/is-it-wrong-to-place-the-script-tag-after-the-body-tag)