# Is it wrong to place the <script type="module"> tag after the </body> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I was reading [this book](https://www.packtpub.com/product/javascript-from-frontend-to-backend/9781801070317). In one of the codes in chapter 5 of the book, I saw the code below:

```html
<!-- index.html file -->
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
</body>

<script type="module">

  import GlobalApp from "./global-app.js";

  var app = Vue.createApp({
    components : {
      GlobalApp:GlobalApp
    },
    template : "<GlobalApp />"
  });

  var vm = app.mount("div#app");

</script>
</html>
```

That code is for a main `html` file that runs a vue app (not in SFC format). If you notice the code, it put `script type="module"` tag after `</body>` tag. I know that there are some similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037725/is-it-wrong-to-place-the-script-tag-after-the-body-tag) in this problem. But I could not found **anything about `script type="module"`** in none of them and this is the **difference** of my question. I want to know that is this usage wrong or non-valid that we put `script type="module"` after `</body>`?

Comment: The `type` attribute makes no difference. See the **Permitted content** for the [<html>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html) tag... _"One `<head>` element, followed by one `<body>` element. "_

Comment: Yes it's invalid HTML, `<html>` can contain only `<head>` or `<body>`. Your script will be moved to the body.

Comment: @Phil thanks for the comment, I just found it in the book, And think that there may be any difference. So the code in the book is wrong?

Comment: It's not valid HTML but it will still (probably) work as intended. Make your own conclusions from that

Comment: is it wrong? yes. Will it break anything? 99.99% of the time, no. If browsers only worked on 100% valid HTML, the world wide web would be a very blank space